# Registration of WP8 device in the WP Developer Center

Tags: windows-phone-8

i just tried to Register my Nokia Lumia 620 with my Windows Phone Developer Account and am getting the same Error as many of you assume to get (Error 0x64).

But the difference in my kind of problem is, that my device (even with the correct ID) is shown up in the overview of my dev account, while the Windows Phone Registration Tool and Visual Studio, when I'm trying to debug my Project, still show up the same Errors (Error 0x64 in Registration and Visual Studio tells me my Device is developer locked).

Did somebody face the same issue and solved it ?

Would be glad for help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That error message & the ErrorCode indicates that your phone was unable to establish a connection to the developer web service portal.

Take a look over this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/wpapps/en-us/17cb951b-6248-4d26-9328-71b584c06401/windows-phone-registration-failing-errorcode-0x64) which has an existing solution.

Comment: Of course I understood this error message, but in that way my phone should not show up in the phone list of my developer account ? Thanks for that Link, I even tried every mentioned solution with no success (Connect to Dev Account using another Computer, using WiFi, SIM Card, rewrite Hosts.conf, restart IPOverUSB Service etc.)